# Advanced custom fields how to style my custom field with css?

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field with the Wordpress Advanced custom field plugin.

In that custom field i put images and i want to style it center on my page with: margin: 0 auto or something.

This is my site: http://www.depurekeuken.nl/new/activiteiten/

I already created a custom field and it works, but i can't find my class name or something to style it center.

Comment: How are you including the ACF content in your page?

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you should be able to right click on the item and select "inspect element" and it should give you it's class.

Like your header on the page; it's class is "custom_headers" and when you're in your css file you can then use that class to change its style.

edit: you can also do that on chrome. 
Additionally on IE you can click f12 and then control B, which will give you the developer toolbar.